# #including <iostream> breaks linkage of shared object

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "Wow, It's working!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Without inclusion of iostream and printing the library links correctly. But when I include and try to print, compiler gives me following errors:

```
Compiling: main.cpp
Linking dynamic library: libfoo.so
/usr/bin/ld: obj/main.o: перемещение R_X86_64_32 для «.rodata» не может использоваться при создании общего объекта; перекомпилируйте с -fPIC
obj/main.o: could not read symbols: Некорректное значение
collect2: ошибка: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата 1
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings
```

Sorry for the errors in Russian, but I have no exact translation into English. Maybe this translation will help:

```
Compiling: main.cpp
Linking dynamic library: libfoo.so
/usr/bin/ld: obj/main.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against ".rodata" can not be used when making shared object; recompile with -fPIC
obj/main.o: could not read symbols: bad value
collect2: error: ld terminated with exit code 1
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings
```

How I must include and compile to get it working?

**P.S.**
The grammar can be very bad: English is not my native language

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `-lstdc++` linker switch? How does your makefile look like?

Comment: No, it is not compile even with `-lstdc++`. I tried to build it manually (I use Code::Blocks IDE) with `g++ -shared -fPIC -o libfoo.so main.cpp` and it's works. I will search why Code::Blocks don't include these flags

Comment: Interesting, so it is some kind of IDE issue? I don't know this IDE, but try to look around where can you indicate that your project is a shared library. Maybe then it'll add the correct flags automatically.

Comment: My -lstdc++ guess was kind of weak, it'd solve a "symbol not found" type error message. Your problem is different.